# Can lists do version control on attachments?

Tags: list, attachments, version-history

All of our project descriptions Word doc attachments to entries in a sharepoint list.

It does not appear that versions of the attachments are being created. When I click on the pulldown arrow and go to previous versions I get a prior version of the list entry, not of any attachments.

Is it possible to have the list create versions each time at attachment is revised?

Or, should this list have been set up as a document library instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One drawback that SharePoint lists have is that attachments are not versioned along with other changes to a list item when list versioning is enabled.

If you want, you can create custom application for it.We need to attach receivers to the ItemAdding, ItemUpdating, ItemAttachmentAdding and ItemAttachmentDeleting methods. These will be used to push the attachments to a document library. Since we will use a document library to store the files, we will need to provision a document library. Finally we will need a custom number field we can use to store the current version of the ListItem....
get complete code from here: [Versioning Attachments in a SharePoint List](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Versioning-Attachments-in-a-SharePoint-List.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should create Document Library and attach the current list fields as meta data properties.

Its even better if you can create a custom document content type and use it as the default content type of the library.

Comment: Amal, thanks. Would it be correct to say that the reason we do not have prior versions of the attachments to our list items is that lists are not capable of doing that?

Comment: Yes attachments are not versioned.